# jquery.Jcrop.js not properly working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jcrop

I am using `jquery.Jcrop.js` for cropping image. I have three images and images coming inside a loop and need to crop separately. My code is working fine in Firefox but in chrome when I crop second image then the control goes to third image (In first image this is working fine) I don't know why. I have checked everything but didn't get any issue. I am using below function

```
 function countTest(){
        $( ".HM_img_cotent .preview" ).each(function( index ) {
        var HM_index = index+1;
        jcrop_api = this;
        $('#cropbox_'+HM_index).Jcrop({
            aspectRatio: 1,
            dragEdges: false,
            //createHandles: ['n','s','e','w','nw','ne','se','sw'],
            onRelease:  function () {
                   clearCoords(HM_index);
            },
            onSelect: function (coords) {
                    updateCoords(coords, HM_index);
            }
        });
     });    
}  

    function updateCoords(c, HM_index)
    {
       $('#x_'+HM_index).val(c.x);
       $('#y_'+HM_index).val(c.y);
       $('#w_'+HM_index).val(c.w);
       $('#h_'+HM_index).val(c.h);
    };

    function clearCoords(HM_index)
    {
       $('#x_'+HM_index).val('');
       $('#y_'+HM_index).val('');
       $('#w_'+HM_index).val('');
       $('#h_'+HM_index).val('');
    };
```

The main function is being called inside a ajax function.

Note: Each image size is 1000px x 1000px.

**[jsfiddle Example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/hirasingh/3qhfjt5y/23/)**

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of this issue.

goto `jquery.Jcrop.js` file.

Find `keySupport: true,`

and replace with

`keySupport: false,`